# powershell error while trying to start process

Tags: windows, powershell

Running PS as admin, trying to run an exe from server (or even if i copy this file to my computer and trying to run it locally)

```
$apps = "\srv\blabla"
Start-Process $apps\mbsetup.exe -Credential $Credentials
```

Error:
[image]

without -credential this would work, i would assume something bad with the user definition but the creds are that of the domain admin.
any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your app requieres administrative privileges. Add `-Verb RunAs` to your `Start-Process` cmdlet to elevate the execution.

But `-Verb RunAs` will not work in combination with `-Credential`. This is a workaround:

```bsh
Start-Process powershell -Credential $Credentials -ArgumentList "-Command &{Start-Process yourApp.exe -Verb RunAs}"
```